# The tableview will move upward while im adding it to the view in the block of gcd queue,how to deal with that?

Tags: ios, tableview, objective-c-blocks

The tableview will move upward while im adding it to the view in the block of gcd queue,how to deal with that?
the problem is cause by the following code

```
[_baseInfoDelegate getBaseInfo:^(NSDictionary *baseInfoDict){
    self.baseInfoDict = baseInfoDict;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self setupTableView];

    });

}];

-(void)setupTableView{
   self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initwithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight)];
   self.tableView.datasource = self;
   self.tableView.delegate = self;
   [self.view addSubview：_tableView];
}
```

is that somebody can help?

Comment: Shiw the code inside -setupTableView.

Comment: hey buddy,here is my code ,any suggestion you have?pls help me ,thx.

Comment: This code looks fine. Are you maybe using auto layout? I'm not very well versed in auto layout, but I think that if you are using that, it might cause this behavior.